# GRAILS - cannot find domain class

Tags: grails

I've created domain class:

```
grails create-domain-class Trip
```

At now I'm trying:

```
grails generate-all Trip
```

But it gives me an error:

> cannot find domain class.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
grails generate-all yourProjectName.Trip
```

When you call `create-domain-class` Grails will [put your domain in a package](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Command%20Line/create-domain-class.html). You need to [specify the domain class package](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.x/ref/Command%20Line/generate-all.html) when calling `generate-all`.